# XML serialization results in duplicate nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have an object structure that I'm trying to serialize to xml that's resulting in a duplicated node level. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with subclassing because I had to implement my own deserialization but I'm not sure exactly what's going on in the other direction. The same xml structure is used as input when deserializing my data at application launch as when reserializing it to be saved later.

Here's what the faulty output xml looks like:

```
<Keyboarding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Exercises>
    <Exercise>
      <Exercise Id="3" ActivityNumber="5" SubActivityNumber="b" Type="Standard">
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Instructions>Downloaded Update Instructions</Instructions>
      </Exercise>
    </Exercise>
  </Exercises>
</Keyboarding>
```

Here's what it should look like (and looks like on initial deserialization):

```
<Keyboarding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Exercises>
      <Exercise Id="3" ActivityNumber="5" SubActivityNumber="b" Type="Standard">
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Instructions>Downloaded Update Instructions</Instructions>
      </Exercise>
  </Exercises>
</Keyboarding>
```

The root object contains a collection of exercises. Exercise is my base class, while subclasses are determined by the Type attribute. I'm using a custom xml serializer to build the objects of varying derived types from Exercise because it allows me to use reflection to match any of the 2 dozen or so potential derived types, which are in an unknown order and quantity when first read in by my application.

Here's the root element's collection, using the custom xml serializer:

```
[XmlArray("Exercises")]
[XmlArrayItem("Exercise", Type = typeof (ExerciseXmlSerializer<Exercise>))]
public Collection<Exercise> UnprocessedExercises { get; set; }
```

My base exercise class is declared as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Exercise
```

And my derived class is declared as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Exercise", IsNullable = false)]
public class StandardExercise : Exercise
```

Here's the writer portion of my custom xml serializer:

```
public class ExerciseXmlSerializer<T> : IXmlSerializable where T : class
{
    private T _data;
    ...
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Type type = _data.GetType();

        new XmlSerializer(type).Serialize(writer, _data);
    }
    ...
}
```

In the WriteXml() method, the type variable is properly set to the derived type, so why does it create a node level for both the base type and the derived type? How do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with this line:

```
[XmlArrayItem("Exercise", Type = typeof (ExerciseXmlSerializer<Exercise>))]
```

I don't think that you want to indicate that the type of the items are a type of the serializer. If you want to implement IXmlSerializable, it needs to be on the class to be serialized.

Here is what I got to work:

```
public class Keyboarding
{
    [XmlArray("Exercises")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Exercise")]
    public Collection<Exercise> UnprocessedExercises { get; set; }

    public Keyboarding()
    {
        UnprocessedExercises = new Collection<Exercise>();
        UnprocessedExercises.Add(new StandardExercise());
    }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(StandardExercise))]
public class Exercise
{
}
[Serializable]
public class StandardExercise : Exercise
{
}
```

This produces output similar to the following:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<Keyboarding xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
  <Exercises>
    <Exercise xsi:type=\"StandardExercise\" />
  </Exercises>
</Keyboarding>
```

If you don't want the `xsi:type` included in the output, you can use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729711/prevent-xmlserializer-from-emitting-xsitype-on-inherited-types).

Comment: Formatting as such breaks when I'm trying to deserialize the initial data, which has the same xml format. When I modified the code and initial xml to match yours, it typed everything as the base type when deserializing and lost all subclassing. I was specifying the type of the items as an xml serializer is because there are almost 2 dozen possible derived classes they can be typed to and an unknown number of items and order in the xml. This let me to take the Type attribute and use reflection in my custom serializer to build the derived objects. I'll edit my question to try to clarify a bit.

Comment: @HotN: Have you tried implementing your custom serialization code directly to the Exercise class? I get exceptions when I try to run the code as it is and it is this `typeof (ExerciseXmlSerializer<Exercise>)` in the XmlArrayItem that is causing the problems. You could also try writing a custom xmlwriter as shown in the answer to the question linked at the end of my answer.

Comment: The problem was definitely caused by the `typeof(ExerciseXmlSerializer<Exercise>)` part but what I found is that changing that to just Exercise would solve the serialization problem but would break my deserialization since the derived class types were determined by an attribute. I got it to work finally by leaving the original code in place for the exercise collection but implementing my own XmlTextWriter, as you suggested. It feels like kind of a convoluted solution, but I do like that it didn't require me to list out 20 derived classes as [XmlInclude]. Anyways, results are results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) to do what you're asking. In this case, you'd probably do something like this. The sample code is a little rough because you didn't include your entire object graph, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

```
List<Type> extraTypes = new List<Type>();
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

extraTypes.Add(typeof(Exercise));
extraTypes.Add(typeof(StandardExercise));

XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute
{
    ElementName = "Exercise",
    Type = typeof(Exercise)
};
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

attr = new XmlElementAttribute
{
    ElementName = "StandardExercise",
    Type = typeof(StandardExercise)
};
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Keyboarding), "Keboarding", attrs);

return new XmlSerializer(typeof(Keyboarding), overrides, extraTypes.ToArray(),
    new XmlRootAttribute("Keyboarding"), string.Empty);
```

This should allow you to create an XML tree that looks like this. It's not quite what you were looking for, but is just as descriptive.

```
<Keyboarding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Exercises>
        <StandardExercise Id="3" ActivityNumber="5" SubActivityNumber="b">
            <Title>Test Title</Title>
            <Instructions>Downloaded Update Instructions</Instructions>
        </StandardExercise >
    </Exercises>
</Keyboarding>
```